# Xcode [NSString floatValue] Rounding Problem

Tags: xcode4, nsstring, rounding

Hi I've a problem with NSString floatValue function, if user insert more than six decimal number floatValue function Round data.

```
NSString *String = @"9.999999";
NSLog(@"Var Float: %f",[String floatValue]);
```

Result 9.999999

```
NSString *String = @"9.9999999";
NSLog(@"Var Float: %f",[String floatValue]);
```

Result 10 ??????

Someone can help me to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use float to manage number precision
Use NSDecimalNumber

```
NSString *Stringa = @"9.9999999";
NSDecimalNumber *Decimal = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:Stringa];
NSLog(@"Var Float: %f",[Decimal floatValue]);
NSLog(@"Var Float: %@",[Decimal stringValue]);
```

Comment: Mine string value is 2499.255 which gets converted to 2499.25488 and in this case NSDecimalNumber to doesn't give me the precise value..

Comment: use [Decimal doubleValue], it will be closer